# post in a lightbox?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

Ive installed "lightbox plus colorbox" plugin and im trying to call the latest post from the CPT notices. the notices have post expiration so essentially im looking to display the latest alert on the homepage.

What ive'e learned from google so far:

```
<?php
    $hotfoodpresent = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'st_notice', 'posts_per_page' =>-1) );
    if($hotfoodpresent) echo '<a class="lbp-inline-link-1 cboxElement" href="#"></a>

 <div style="display: none;">
   <div id="lbp-inline-href-1" style="padding:10px; background: #fff;">

 <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()):the_post();
    wp_redirect(get_permalink());

    endwhile;
 endif; ?>

 </div>
</div>'; ?>
```

But I think im going about this the wrong way as I don't see anything in the pop-up.

I would not like to use plugins as this wordpress installation will remain on a local network without internet access.

Thankyou in advance for the help if you can!

Revision 2

```
 <div class="lbp-inline-link-1 cboxElement">

 <div style="display: none;">
 <div id="lbp-inline-href-1" style="padding:10px; background: #fff;">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php  endwhile; ?>
 <?php  endif; ?>
```

Revision 3

```
<div class="lbp-inline-link-1 cboxElement">
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="lbp-inline-href-1" style="padding:10px; background: #fff;">

   <?php
        $args = array(
          'posts_per_page' => 1,
          'post_type' => 'st_notice'
                     );
       query_posts($args);
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><P>Please click here for further information </a></p>


</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php  endwhile; ?>
 <?php  endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your code so that's properly indented?  It's very hard to read as is.

Comment: any better?....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code cannot work. At first, your `endwhile;` and `endif` statements are inside the string. They will be printed and not executed. The correct formatted code should look like this

```
$hotfoodpresent = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'st_notice', 'posts_per_page' =>-1) );

if ( $hotfoodpresent )
    echo '<a class="lbp-inline-link-1 cboxElement" href="#"></a>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <div id="lbp-inline-href-1" style="padding:10px; background: #fff;">';

    if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
    endwhile;

    echo '  </div>';    
    echo '</div>';
endif;
```

But I still wonder what this code block should do

```
if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
endwhile;
```

After `wp_redirect()` you have to exit the code with `exit()` or `die()`. But before you use `wp_redirect()`, you cannot print anything. This will result in a `Headers already send` error.
`wp_redirect()` do **not** print anything to the screen. There is no other code that will output anything. So what do you want to see if the lightbox open?

Maybe try `printf( '<a href="%s">Redirect</a>', get_permalink() );` instead of `wp_redirect()`und you will get a link with the text 'Redirect'.

Comment: Ralf912 you were right, the redirect link appears and this reloads the home page when clicked.

Comment: Maybe ... umh ... you should try to print the post? I think it is worth to give it a try.

Comment: revision 2 in my orginal post now gives me a home link in the lightbox. I need to figure out how to get a CPT

Comment: And the link text is what? Maybe your posts are simply empty and that's the reason why you didn't see anything.

Comment: Revision 3 works perfectly thanks for you help ralf